# How to handle RabbitMQ tasks w/ different memory footprints being queued to the same exchange?

Tags: node.js, memory, rabbitmq

Imagine a RabbitMQ queue that collects "tasks" essentially. These tasks are then retrieved by a Node.js app with a `prefetch` value of 100. So, the app prefetches up to 100 tasks to do and then processes them when possible.

The issue with this setup is that the tasks can have a different memory footprint and thus it is difficult to predict what sort of `prefetch` value I can set before the Node.js app runs out of memory. For some of the smaller tasks, I could prefetch a 100 of them and the app would run fine, and then some task payloads could cause the app to use more memory than usually and only a prefetch of 50 would be okay before the app runs out of memory.

I could split these tasks in different queues or try to normalize them so that they have a more standard memory footprint. What other sort of approaches can you suggest?

Comment: How do you define the size of the task? Is it known beforehand?

Comment: Sort of, but it isn't possible to accurately predict it. The task payload (the data actually queued on RabbitMQ) could be pretty small, but because of corresponding data stored in a DB that could be pretty big, the memory footprint could still be big.